# Items_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object) is not processing multiple items that come in at the same time

Tags: vba, outlook

If only one email is sent at a time then my code works fine, otherwise, if multiple items come in at the same time then only one of the emails is processed and moved. Basically, my code is processing items as they come into outlook. And if the email is received as a distribution list then the email is sent to a sub folder based on the distribution list name and time of day.

Here's my code:

```
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
  Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
  Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
  Set olApp = Outlook.Application
  Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  Set Items = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal cusItem As Object)
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Items = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
    
    Dim strEntryID As String
    Dim objAddressentry As Outlook.AddressEntry
    Dim objRecipient As Outlook.Recipient
    Dim objDestFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim objRecs As Outlook.Recipients
    Dim i As Integer
    
    If TypeName(cusItem) = "MailItem" Then
        
        On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
        
        Set objRecs = cusItem.Recipients
        
        For i = 1 To objRecs.Count
        
            Set objRecipient = objRecs.Item(i)
        
            strEntryID = objRecipient.EntryID

            Set objAddressentry = objNS.GetAddressEntryFromID(strEntryID)
   
            If objAddressentry = "amazonselling" And TimeValue(Now()) >= TimeValue("08:00:00 AM") And TimeValue(Now()) <= TimeValue("05:00:00 PM") Then
        
            Set objDestFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("ryule")
    
            cusItem.Move objDestFolder
            
            Exit For
        
            End If
        
        Next

    End If

ProgramExit:
  Exit Sub
  
ErrorHandler:
  MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description & vbCrLf & "Click Ok to continue operations"
  Resume ProgramExit
    
End Sub
```

Also, if I don't declare and set those variables twice then my code doesn't work as intended. Why is that and how could that be fixed?

Comment: You don't need to do this `Set Items = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items` inside `Items_ItemAdd` - resetting that is likely the cause of your problem here.

Comment: Tested and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `ItemAdd` event is not fired when a large number of items are added to the folder at once (more than sixteen). This is a known issue when dealing with the Outlook object model. Instead, I'd suggest considering the `NewMailEx` event which is fired when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. You can use the Entry ID returned in the EntryIDCollection array to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method and process the item.

Anyway, it seems the problem is in your code, try to remove additional declarations from both methods:

```
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items
Private objNS As Outlook.NameSpace

Private Sub Application_Startup()
  Set objNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  Set Items = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal cusItem As Object)
    Dim strEntryID As String
    Dim objAddressentry As Outlook.AddressEntry
    Dim objRecipient As Outlook.Recipient
    Dim objDestFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim objRecs As Outlook.Recipients
    Dim i As Integer
    
    If TypeName(cusItem) = "MailItem" Then
        
        On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
        
        Set objRecs = cusItem.Recipients
        
        For i = 1 To objRecs.Count
        
            Set objRecipient = objRecs.Item(i)
        
            strEntryID = objRecipient.EntryID

            Set objAddressentry = objNS.GetAddressEntryFromID(strEntryID)
   
            If objAddressentry = "amazonselling" And TimeValue(Now()) >= TimeValue("08:00:00 AM") And TimeValue(Now()) <= TimeValue("05:00:00 PM") Then
        
            Set objDestFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("ryule")
    
            cusItem.Move objDestFolder
            
            Exit For
        
            End If
        
        Next

    End If

ProgramExit:
  Exit Sub
  
ErrorHandler:
  MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description & vbCrLf & "Click Ok to continue operations"
  Resume ProgramExit
    
End Sub
```